# difference between @ContextConfiguration and @Import in test classes

Tags: spring, testing, annotations

i currently study the purpose of the the spring annotation @ContextConfiguration
and i wonder what is the difference with the @Import annotation.

In fact, when i use these snippet..

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import({SpringService.class,SpringService2.class})
public class Snippet1 {

    @Autowired
    SpringService springService;

    @Autowired
    SpringService2 springService2;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(springService);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(springService2);
    }
}
```

or this one..

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringService.class,SpringService2.class})
public class Snippet2 {

    @Autowired
    SpringService springService;

    @Autowired
    SpringService2 springService2;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(springService);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(springService2);
    }
}
```

it is exactly the same !
What is the sutbility ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the example you are using they would behave the same.  The import annotation allows you to compose multiple configuration classes together:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/composing-configuration-classes.html#beans-java-using-import

You example for Snippet2 could use the class annotated with @Import:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Snippet1 .class})
public class Snippet2 {

    @Autowired
    SpringService springService;

    @Autowired
    SpringService2 springService2;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(springService);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(springService2);
    }
}
```

Using the @Import that way allows you to not repeat yourself by having to keep defining the same list of classes in your ContextConfiguration over an over again.  You would also want to mark it with the @Configuration annotation and not have the @ExtendsWith annotation since you are just using it to define a Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import({SpringService.class,SpringService2.class})
public class Snippet1 {
}
```

Spring's documentation is excellent and I would recommend you read the link I posted.